# TSQL - struggling with simple where condition

Tags: t-sql

```
select 
    b.id, b.status, 
    b.max_log_data, 
    b.rn
from 
( 
    select 
    a.id, a.status, 
    a.max_log_date, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id order by a.max_log_date) as rn
    from 
    (
        select id, status, max(log_date)'max_log_date' 
        from LOG_table where id=1234
        group by id, status
    ) as a 
) as b 
where ????
```

So in results without where condition I have different statuses with dates and row numbers (rn), but I need spesific date where row number is equal to row number with spesific status + 1

Basically I need where conditione: b.rn=((b.nr with spesific status) + 1)

Tried something like this, but this is not working: b.rn=(case when b.status='sold' then b.rn+1 end)

Comment: Example data would be useful. Also, shouldn't your case have an else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't filter a row with a value from another row in a simple `WHERE` condition without subqueries. You need to join them together to be able to apply an expression that involves those columns.

I find using the CTE syntax way better to read than subqueries:

```
;WITH MaxLogDates AS 
(
    select 
        id, 
        status, 
        max(log_date) AS max_log_date
    from 
        LOG_table 
    where 
        id=1234
    group by 
        id, 
        status
),
RowNumbers AS
(
    select 
        a.id, 
        a.status, 
        a.max_log_date, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id order by a.max_log_date) as rn
    from 
        MaxLogDates as a
),
FilteredStatusRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT
        R.id,
        R.status,
        R.max_log_date,
        R.rn AS SpecificRN
    FROM
        RowNumbers AS R
    WHERE
        R.Status = 'Some Specific Status'
)
select 
    r.id, 
    r.status, 
    r.max_log_data, 
    r.rn
from 
    RowNumbers as r
    INNER JOIN FilteredStatusRowNumber AS f on
        r.id = f.id AND
        R.rn = f.SpecificRN + 1
```

You can also directly apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` against a `MAX()` aggregate value and kill 2 birds with 1 stone:

```
select 
    id, 
    status, 
    max(log_date) AS max_log_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id order by max(log_date)) as rn
from 
    LOG_table 
where 
    id=1234
group by 
    id, 
    status
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. But one additional question as I have to use this part inside another query. How it is possible to add this part into my existing query. I hoped that it would work with outer apply, but I didnt get it to work.

Comment: @Ziil just join or wrap this in another CTE like the 3 examples here. I can't help you without seeing what you want to incorporate this into.

Comment: basically I would like to join this CTE syntax to my existing query, but I am not sure how to do it, I thought something lik this:


`Outer Apply (
;WITH MaxLogDates AS   
  (  
      select   
          id,   
          status,   
          max(log_date) AS max_log_date  
      from   
          LOG_table   
      where   
          id=my_another_table_id
  ...`